# USB devices are not detected in guest OS

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have ubuntu as Guest OS in virtualbox. My host OS is also ubuntu(version 14.10).
To do a personal project, I want to detect my android phone in guest OS. By default, Iam unable to see my phone under USB devices. Can someone guide me to find USB devices in my ubuntu guest OS?

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

To use USB devices in the guest you need to download and install the Extension Pack for VirtualBox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads .